# Run controller PHP codeigniter function with ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, controller

I'm trying to run function `getVideos()` from my controller using ajax but I got a 404 error.

Is there any problem with the url or the route?

**videos.php** (Controller)

```
public function getVideos(){

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);  


    echo json_encode($ch);
}
```

**main.js**

```
$.get("videos/getVideos", function(data, status){
        console.log(data);
});
```

**routes.php**

```
 $route["videos"] = "videos/get_videos/";
```

Comment: Try this `site_url('videos/getVideos')`

Comment: Wait what! What is the name of your controller and is it inside a dir called videos?

Comment: are you sure you need routes for this? what is your file structure for this?

Comment: Just use the url you don't need a reroute and if your controller is inside a folder pass the full structure like this `site_url('videos/get_videos/getVideos')` .. if that's the structure you are using

Comment: @SherifSalah yes, that worked more or less. PHP `site_url()` and `base_url()` doesn't work (not sure why) but saving it's value on a js variable does the job

Comment: Great, happy it worked bro .. about `site_url` and `base_url` you have to set the `base_url` manually in `config.php` when it doesn't work properly.

Comment: @SherifSalah actually is working in php files but not in js, that's why I don't understand

Comment: You want a php code to be executable in a .js file? .. if you want to use php inside a script then write the script inside a .php file not a .js file

Comment: or save the variable to a global js variable in php header and then it will be available in all .js files as long as they are called after the var is declared. seems like you did that - but yea, its the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

This probably help

```
site_url('videos/getVideos')
```

or  write the full url in your ajax

```
mydomain.com/videos/getVideos
```

and by the way you don't need to create a manual route for it because codeigniter framework allow to auto generate a route for you via controller and method.

Help this give you an idea.